# Dedicated Centos 7.2/Plesk 12.5 server most services Fail on boot

Tags: centos7, dedicated

I have this dedicated server which was running like a charm for 1.5 year since this morning when it restarted (for reasons I still do not know) and never booted again.
I logged with KVM and I can see it hanging on boot with most of the services failing
ssh connection refuses so I managed to boot with rescue system and find the logs

this must be the incident(but I am not that experienced so I am not sure):

```html
Jan 17 02:09:58 dedicated-server1 chronyd[769]: chronyd version 2.1.1 starting (+CMDMON +NTP +REFCLOCK +RTC +PRIVDROP +DEBUG +ASYNCDNS +IPV6 +SECHASH)
Jan 17 02:09:58 dedicated-server1 systemd: Starting The PHP 5.5.38 FastCGI Process Manager...
Jan 17 02:09:58 dedicated-server1 systemd: Starting Dump dmesg to /var/log/dmesg...
Jan 17 02:09:58 dedicated-server1 systemd: Starting Login Service...
Jan 17 02:09:58 dedicated-server1 systemd: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Jan 17 02:09:58 dedicated-server1 systemd: Starting Startup script for Plesk control panel server...
Jan 17 02:09:58 dedicated-server1 systemd: Starting Dynamic System Tuning Daemon...
Jan 17 02:09:58 dedicated-server1 systemd: Starting MagicSpam AntiSpam service daemon...
Jan 17 02:09:58 dedicated-server1 systemd: Starting ACPI Event Daemon...
Jan 17 02:09:58 dedicated-server1 systemd: Started Dovecot IMAP/POP3 email server.
Jan 17 02:09:58 dedicated-server1 systemd: Starting Dovecot IMAP/POP3 email server...
Jan 17 02:09:58 dedicated-server1 systemd: Started D-Bus System Message Bus.
Jan 17 02:09:58 dedicated-server1 dbus-daemon: Could not get password database information for UID of current process: User "???" unknown or no memory to allocate password entry
Jan 17 02:09:58 dedicated-server1 dbus-daemon: Unknown username "root" in message bus configuration file
Jan 17 02:09:58 dedicated-server1 dbus-daemon: Could not get password database information for UID of current process: User "???" unknown or no memory to allocate password entry
Jan 17 02:09:58 dedicated-server1 dbus-daemon: Unknown username "root" in message bus configuration file
Jan 17 02:09:58 dedicated-server1 dbus-daemon: Could not get password database information for UID of current process: User "???" unknown or no memory to allocate password entry
Jan 17 02:09:58 dedicated-server1 dbus-daemon: Unknown username "root" in message bus configuration file
Jan 17 02:09:58 dedicated-server1 chronyd[769]: Fatal error : getpwnam(chrony) failed
Jan 17 02:09:58 dedicated-server1 chronyd: getpwnam(chrony) failed
Jan 17 02:09:58 dedicated-server1 dbus-daemon: Could not get password database information for UID of current process: User "???" unknown or no memory to allocate password entry
Jan 17 02:09:58 dedicated-server1 dbus-daemon: Unknown username "root" in message bus configuration file
Jan 17 02:09:58 dedicated-server1 dbus-daemon: Could not get password database information for UID of current process: User "???" unknown or no memory to allocate password entry
Jan 17 02:09:58 dedicated-server1 dbus-daemon: Unknown username "root" in message bus configuration file
Jan 17 02:09:58 dedicated-server1 dbus-daemon: Could not get password database information for UID of current process: User "???" unknown or no memory to allocate password entry
Jan 17 02:09:58 dedicated-server1 dbus-daemon: Unknown username "root" in message bus configuration file
Jan 17 02:09:58 dedicated-server1 dbus-daemon: Could not get password database information for UID of current process: User "???" unknown or no memory to allocate password entry
Jan 17 02:09:58 dedicated-server1 dbus-daemon: Unknown username "root" in message bus configuration file
Jan 17 02:09:58 dedicated-server1 dbus-daemon: Could not get password database information for UID of current process: User "???" unknown or no memory to allocate password entry
Jan 17 02:09:58 dedicated-server1 dbus-daemon: Unknown username "root" in message bus configuration file
Jan 17 02:09:58 dedicated-server1 dbus-daemon: Could not get password database information for UID of current process: User "???" unknown or no memory to allocate password entry
Jan 17 02:09:58 dedicated-server1 dbus-daemon: Failed to start message bus: Could not get UID and GID for username "dbus"
Jan 17 02:09:58 dedicated-server1 magicspam-daemon: Starting magicspam-daemon ...groupadd: group 'magicspam' already exists
Jan 17 02:09:58 dedicated-server1 magicspam-daemon: Failed to initialize user magicspam
Jan 17 02:09:58 dedicated-server1 smartd[764]: smartd 6.2 2013-07-26 r3841 [x86_64-linux-3.10.0-327.28.3.el7.x86_64] (local build)
Jan 17 02:09:58 dedicated-server1 smartd[764]: Copyright (C) 2002-13, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org
Jan 17 02:09:58 dedicated-server1 smartd[764]: Opened configuration file /etc/smartmontools/smartd.conf
Jan 17 02:09:58 dedicated-server1 smartd[764]: Configuration file /etc/smartmontools/smartd.conf was parsed, found DEVICESCAN, scanning devices
Jan 17 02:09:58 dedicated-server1 smartd[764]: Device: /dev/sda, type changed from 'scsi' to 'sat'
Jan 17 02:09:58 dedicated-server1 smartd[764]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], opened
Jan 17 02:09:58 dedicated-server1 smartd[764]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], SAMSUNG MZ7LM480HCHP-00003, S/N:S1YJNXAG800123, WWN:5-002538-c4002e9d0, FW:GXT3003Q, 480 GB
Jan 17 02:09:58 dedicated-server1 tuned: Traceback (most recent call last):
Jan 17 02:09:58 dedicated-server1 tuned: File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site.py", line 556, in <module>
Jan 17 02:09:58 dedicated-server1 smartd[764]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], not found in smartd database.
Jan 17 02:09:58 dedicated-server1 tuned: main()
Jan 17 02:09:58 dedicated-server1 tuned: File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site.py", line 538, in main
Jan 17 02:09:58 dedicated-server1 tuned: known_paths = addusersitepackages(known_paths)
Jan 17 02:09:58 dedicated-server1 tuned: File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site.py", line 266, in addusersitepackages
Jan 17 02:09:58 dedicated-server1 tuned: user_site = getusersitepackages()
Jan 17 02:09:58 dedicated-server1 tuned: File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site.py", line 241, in getusersitepackages
Jan 17 02:09:58 dedicated-server1 tuned: user_base = getuserbase() # this will also set USER_BASE
Jan 17 02:09:58 dedicated-server1 tuned: File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site.py", line 231, in getuserbase
Jan 17 02:09:58 dedicated-server1 tuned: USER_BASE = get_config_var('userbase')
Jan 17 02:09:58 dedicated-server1 tuned: File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/sysconfig.py", line 516, in get_config_var
Jan 17 02:09:58 dedicated-server1 tuned: return get_config_vars().get(name)
Jan 17 02:09:58 dedicated-server1 tuned: File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/sysconfig.py", line 473, in get_config_vars
Jan 17 02:09:58 dedicated-server1 tuned: _CONFIG_VARS['userbase'] = _getuserbase()
Jan 17 02:09:58 dedicated-server1 tuned: File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/sysconfig.py", line 187, in _getuserbase
Jan 17 02:09:58 dedicated-server1 tuned: return env_base if env_base else joinuser("~", ".local")
Jan 17 02:09:58 dedicated-server1 tuned: File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/sysconfig.py", line 173, in joinuser
Jan 17 02:09:58 dedicated-server1 tuned: return os.path.expanduser(os.path.join(*args))
Jan 17 02:09:58 dedicated-server1 tuned: File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/posixpath.py", line 269, in expanduser
Jan 17 02:09:58 dedicated-server1 tuned: userhome = pwd.getpwuid(os.getuid()).pw_dir
Jan 17 02:09:58 dedicated-server1 tuned: KeyError: 'getpwuid(): uid not found: 0'
Jan 17 02:09:58 dedicated-server1 smartd[764]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], can't monitor Offline_Uncorrectable count - no Attribute 198
Jan 17 02:09:58 dedicated-server1 smartd[764]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], is SMART capable. Adding to "monitor" list.
Jan 17 02:09:58 dedicated-server1 dovecot: doveconf: Fatal: Error in configuration file /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf: default_login_user doesn't exist: dovenull
Jan 17 02:09:58 dedicated-server1 smartd[764]: Device: /dev/sdb, type changed from 'scsi' to 'sat'
Jan 17 02:09:58 dedicated-server1 smartd[764]: Device: /dev/sdb [SAT], opened
Jan 17 02:09:58 dedicated-server1 smartd[764]: Device: /dev/sdb [SAT], SAMSUNG MZ7LM480HCHP-00003, S/N:S1YJNXAG800115, WWN:5-002538-c4002e9c8, FW:GXT3003Q, 480 GB
Jan 17 02:09:58 dedicated-server1 sw-cp-serverd: nginx: [emerg] getpwnam("sw-cp-server") failed
Jan 17 02:09:58 dedicated-server1 sw-cp-serverd: nginx: configuration file /etc/sw-cp-server/config test failed
Jan 17 02:09:58 dedicated-server1 smartd[764]: Device: /dev/sdb [SAT], not found in smartd database.
Jan 17 02:09:58 dedicated-server1 smartd[764]: Device: /dev/sdb [SAT], can't monitor Offline_Uncorrectable count - no Attribute 198
Jan 17 02:09:58 dedicated-server1 smartd[764]: Device: /dev/sdb [SAT], is SMART capable. Adding to "monitor" list.
Jan 17 02:09:58 dedicated-server1 smartd[764]: Monitoring 2 ATA and 0 SCSI devices
Jan 17 02:09:58 dedicated-server1 network: Bringing up loopback interface:  [  OK  ]
Jan 17 02:09:58 dedicated-server1 php-fpm: [17-Jan-2018 02:09:58] ERROR: [pool pros247.net] cannot get uid for user 'pros247net'
Jan 17 02:09:58 dedicated-server1 php-fpm: [17-Jan-2018 02:09:58] ERROR: FPM initialization failed
Jan 17 02:09:58 dedicated-server1 acpid: starting up with netlink and the input layer
Jan 17 02:09:58 dedicated-server1 acpid: skipping incomplete file /etc/acpi/events/videoconf
Jan 17 02:09:58 dedicated-server1 acpid: 1 rule loaded
Jan 17 02:09:58 dedicated-server1 acpid: waiting for events: event logging is off
Jan 17 02:09:58 dedicated-server1 httpd: AH00543: httpd: bad user name apache
Jan 17 02:09:58 dedicated-server1 kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
Jan 17 02:09:58 dedicated-server1 php-fpm: [17-Jan-2018 02:09:58] ERROR: [pool legacy.prosfair.net] cannot get uid for user 'prosfair'
Jan 17 02:09:58 dedicated-server1 php-fpm: [17-Jan-2018 02:09:58] ERROR: FPM initialization failed
Jan 17 02:10:00 dedicated-server1 network: Bringing up interface eth0:  [  OK  ]
Jan 17 02:10:01 dedicated-server1 kernel: igb 0000:03:00.0 eth0: igb: eth0 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: RX/TX
Jan 17 02:10:01 dedicated-server1 kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Jan 17 02:10:09 dedicated-server1 kernel: md: md2: resync done.
Jan 17 02:10:23 dedicated-server1 systemd: Failed to register match for Disconnected message: Connection timed out
Jan 17 02:10:23 dedicated-server1 systemd-logind: Failed to add match for NameOwnerChanged: Connection timed out
Jan 17 02:10:23 dedicated-server1 systemd-logind: Failed to fully start up daemon: Connection timed out
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 systemd: Failed to register match for Disconnected message: Connection timed out
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 systemd: Starting D-Bus System Message Bus...
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 systemd: Starting The PHP 7.0.27 FastCGI Process Manager...
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 systemd: Starting MariaDB database server...
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 systemd: Starting Permit User Sessions...
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 systemd: Failed at step USER spawning /usr/libexec/mariadb-prepare-db-dir: No such process
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 systemd: Started irqbalance daemon.
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 systemd: Starting irqbalance daemon...
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 systemd: Starting MagicSpam milter service for Postfix integration...
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 systemd: Starting Postfix Mail Transport Agent...
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 systemd: Started Plesk mail filter service for Postfix.
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 systemd: Starting Plesk mail filter service for Postfix...
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 systemd: Started Generic clamav scanner daemon.
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 systemd: Starting Generic clamav scanner daemon...
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 systemd: Starting System Logging Service...
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 systemd: Starting Software RAID monitoring and management...
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 psa-pc-remote: Unable to get user 'postfix' passwd record (0): Success
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 systemd: Starting Spamassassin daemon...
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 systemd: Starting Fail2Ban Service...
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 systemd: Starting Startup script for Panel sw-engine...
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 systemd: Starting The PHP 5.4.45 FastCGI Process Manager...
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 systemd: Starting /etc/rc.d/rc.local Compatibility...
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 systemd: Starting Startup script for nginx service...
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 systemd: Started OpenSSH server daemon.
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 magicspam-milter: Starting magicspam-milter ...groupadd: group 'magicspam' already exists
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 magicspam-milter: Failed to initialize user magicspam
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 systemd: Starting OpenSSH server daemon...
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 systemd: Starting Xinetd A Powerful Replacement For Inetd...
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 systemd: Starting The PHP 5.6.33 FastCGI Process Manager...
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 systemd: Started Daily Cleanup of Temporary Directories.
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 systemd: Starting Daily Cleanup of Temporary Directories.
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 systemd: Reached target Timers.
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 systemd: Starting Timers.
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 systemd: Started System Logging Service.
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 systemd: Started LSB: Bring up/down networking.
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 systemd: chronyd.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 systemd: Failed to start NTP client/server.
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 systemd: Unit chronyd.service entered failed state.
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 systemd: chronyd.service failed.
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 systemd: php-fpm.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=78/n/a
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 sshd: Privilege separation user sshd does not exist
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 systemd: Failed to start The PHP FastCGI Process Manager.
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 systemd: Unit php-fpm.service entered failed state.
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 systemd: php-fpm.service failed.
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 systemd: plesk-php55-fpm.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=78/n/a
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 xinetd[1071]: Unknown user: root [file=/etc/xinetd.d/ftp_psa] [line=13]
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 systemd: Failed to start The PHP 5.5.38 FastCGI Process Manager.
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 xinetd[1071]: Error parsing attribute user - DISABLING SERVICE [file=/etc/xinetd.d/ftp_psa] [line=13]
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 systemd: Unit plesk-php55-fpm.service entered failed state.
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 systemd: plesk-php55-fpm.service failed.
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 xinetd[1071]: Unknown user: root [file=/etc/xinetd.d/poppassd_psa] [line=12]
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 systemd: Started Dump dmesg to /var/log/dmesg.
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 xinetd[1071]: Error parsing attribute user - DISABLING SERVICE [file=/etc/xinetd.d/poppassd_psa] [line=12]
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 systemd: systemd-logind.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 systemd: Failed to start Login Service.
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 systemd: Unit systemd-logind.service entered failed state.
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 systemd: systemd-logind.service failed.
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 systemd: httpd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 systemd: sw-cp-server.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 systemd: Failed to start Startup script for Plesk control panel server.
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 systemd: Dependency failed for Plesk Panel.
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 systemd: Job psa.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 systemd: Unit sw-cp-server.service entered failed state.
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 systemd: sw-cp-server.service failed.
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 systemd: tuned.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 systemd: Failed to start Dynamic System Tuning Daemon.
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 systemd: Unit tuned.service entered failed state.
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 systemd: tuned.service failed.
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 systemd: magicspam-daemon.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 kill: kill: cannot find process ""
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 systemd: Failed to start MagicSpam AntiSpam service daemon.
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 xinetd[1071]: xinetd Version 2.3.15 started with libwrap loadavg labeled-networking options compiled in.
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 systemd: Unit magicspam-daemon.service entered failed state.
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 xinetd[1071]: Started working: 0 available services
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 systemd: magicspam-daemon.service failed.
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 systemd: Started ACPI Event Daemon.
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 systemd: dovecot.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=89/n/a
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 systemd: Unit dovecot.service entered failed state.
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 systemd: dovecot.service failed.
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 systemd: dbus.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 systemd: Unit dbus.service entered failed state.
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 systemd: dbus.service failed.
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 systemd: mariadb.service: control process exited, code=exited status=217
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 systemd: Failed to start MariaDB database server.
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 systemd: Unit mariadb.service entered failed state.
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 systemd: mariadb.service failed.
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 systemd: Started Permit User Sessions.
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 systemd: magicspam-milter.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 systemd: Failed to start MagicSpam milter service for Postfix integration.
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 systemd: Unit magicspam-milter.service entered failed state.
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 systemd: magicspam-milter.service failed.
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 systemd: pc-remote.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=69/n/a
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 systemd: Unit pc-remote.service entered failed state.
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 systemd: pc-remote.service failed.
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 systemd: Started Software RAID monitoring and management.
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 systemd: Started /etc/rc.d/rc.local Compatibility.
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 systemd: sshd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=255/n/a
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 systemd: Unit sshd.service entered failed state.
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 systemd: sshd.service failed.
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 systemd: Started Xinetd A Powerful Replacement For Inetd.
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 systemd: httpd.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 systemd: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 systemd: Unit httpd.service entered failed state.
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 systemd: httpd.service failed.
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 systemd: systemd-logind.service has no holdoff time, scheduling restart.
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 clamd: ERROR: Can't get information about user clamscan.
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 fail2ban-client: Traceback (most recent call last):
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 fail2ban-client: File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site.py", line 556, in <module>
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 fail2ban-client: main()
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 fail2ban-client: File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site.py", line 538, in main
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 fail2ban-client: known_paths = addusersitepackages(known_paths)
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 fail2ban-client: File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site.py", line 266, in addusersitepackages
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 fail2ban-client: user_site = getusersitepackages()
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 fail2ban-client: File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site.py", line 241, in getusersitepackages
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 fail2ban-client: user_base = getuserbase() # this will also set USER_BASE
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 fail2ban-client: File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site.py", line 231, in getuserbase
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 fail2ban-client: USER_BASE = get_config_var('userbase')
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 fail2ban-client: File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/sysconfig.py", line 516, in get_config_var
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 fail2ban-client: return get_config_vars().get(name)
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 fail2ban-client: File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/sysconfig.py", line 473, in get_config_vars
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 fail2ban-client: _CONFIG_VARS['userbase'] = _getuserbase()
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 fail2ban-client: File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/sysconfig.py", line 187, in _getuserbase
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 fail2ban-client: return env_base if env_base else joinuser("~", ".local")
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 fail2ban-client: File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/sysconfig.py", line 173, in joinuser
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 fail2ban-client: return os.path.expanduser(os.path.join(*args))
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 fail2ban-client: File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/posixpath.py", line 269, in expanduser
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 fail2ban-client: userhome = pwd.getpwuid(os.getuid()).pw_dir
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 fail2ban-client: KeyError: 'getpwuid(): uid not found: 0'
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 systemd: fail2ban.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 systemd: Failed to start Fail2Ban Service.
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 systemd: Unit fail2ban.service entered failed state.
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 systemd: fail2ban.service failed.
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 systemd: clamd@scan.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 systemd: Unit clamd@scan.service entered failed state.
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 systemd: clamd@scan.service failed.
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 nginx: nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 nginx: nginx: [emerg] getpwnam("nginx") failed
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 nginx: nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 systemd: nginx.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 systemd: Failed to start Startup script for nginx service.
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 systemd: Unit nginx.service entered failed state.
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 systemd: nginx.service failed.
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 systemd: Looping too fast. Throttling execution a little.
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 php-fpm: [17-Jan-2018 02:10:48] ERROR: [pool beta.prosfair.net] cannot get uid for user 'prosfair'
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 php-fpm: [17-Jan-2018 02:10:48] ERROR: FPM initialization failed
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 php-fpm: [17-Jan-2018 02:10:48] ERROR: [pool prostech.net] cannot get uid for user 'prostechnet'
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 php-fpm: [17-Jan-2018 02:10:48] ERROR: FPM initialization failed
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 php-fpm: [17-Jan-2018 02:10:48] ERROR: [pool prosbet.net] cannot get uid for user 'prosbetnet'
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 php-fpm: [17-Jan-2018 02:10:48] ERROR: FPM initialization failed
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 sw-engine-fpm: [17-Jan-2018 02:10:48] ERROR: [pool plesk] cannot get uid for user 'psaadm'
Jan 17 02:10:48 dedicated-server1 sw-engine-fpm: [17-Jan-2018 02:10:48] ERROR: FPM initialization failed
Jan 17 02:10:49 dedicated-server1 systemd: plesk-php70-fpm.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=78/n/a
Jan 17 02:10:49 dedicated-server1 systemd: Failed to start The PHP 7.0.27 FastCGI Process Manager.
Jan 17 02:10:49 dedicated-server1 systemd: Unit plesk-php70-fpm.service entered failed state.
Jan 17 02:10:49 dedicated-server1 systemd: plesk-php70-fpm.service failed.
Jan 17 02:10:49 dedicated-server1 systemd: sw-engine.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=78/n/a
Jan 17 02:10:49 dedicated-server1 systemd: Failed to start Startup script for Panel sw-engine.
Jan 17 02:10:49 dedicated-server1 systemd: Unit sw-engine.service entered failed state.
Jan 17 02:10:49 dedicated-server1 systemd: sw-engine.service failed.
Jan 17 02:10:49 dedicated-server1 systemd: plesk-php54-fpm.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=78/n/a
Jan 17 02:10:49 dedicated-server1 systemd: Failed to start The PHP 5.4.45 FastCGI Process Manager.
Jan 17 02:10:49 dedicated-server1 systemd: Unit plesk-php54-fpm.service entered failed state.
Jan 17 02:10:49 dedicated-server1 systemd: plesk-php54-fpm.service failed.
Jan 17 02:10:49 dedicated-server1 systemd: plesk-php56-fpm.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=78/n/a
Jan 17 02:10:49 dedicated-server1 systemd: Failed to start The PHP 5.6.33 FastCGI Process Manager.
Jan 17 02:10:49 dedicated-server1 systemd: Unit plesk-php56-fpm.service entered failed state.
Jan 17 02:10:49 dedicated-server1 systemd: plesk-php56-fpm.service failed.
Jan 17 02:10:49 dedicated-server1 systemd: Started Spamassassin daemon.
Jan 17 02:10:49 dedicated-server1 systemd: postfix.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jan 17 02:10:49 dedicated-server1 systemd: Failed to start Postfix Mail Transport Agent.
Jan 17 02:10:49 dedicated-server1 systemd: Unit postfix.service entered failed state.
Jan 17 02:10:49 dedicated-server1 systemd: postfix.service failed.
Jan 17 02:10:49 dedicated-server1 systemd: clamd@scan.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Jan 17 02:10:49 dedicated-server1 systemd: fail2ban.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Jan 17 02:10:49 dedicated-server1 systemd: Looping too fast. Throttling execution a little.
Jan 17 02:10:50 dedicated-server1 systemd: Looping too fast. Throttling execution a little.
```

any suggestions would be highly appreciated

thank you in advance

Comment: Looks like there is a dbus daemon failure "Failed to start message bus: Could not get UID and GID for username "dbus""

Comment: Inspect dmesg logs to find out startup error. http://www.linfo.org/dmesg.html

Comment: got them downloaded. both dmesg and .old, no dbus in there..:( thank you for you help. i am looking into this daemon failure.

Comment: still searching this error, nothing yet. Meanwhile i asked the hosting company and they did a full hardware scan which came up clean as new. Booted with rescue system, clean dmesg, rebooted to centos and back to rescue to get the dmesg. first timer with such thing, it seems ok... to my noob eyes at least. still this is hardware/driver related and i get the feeling this isn't my problem. well my main problem is the lack of knowledge so if anyone can lend one more hand... :) i have a server down, i am lost.

Comment: Try posting this on unix.stackexchange.com.

Comment: ok, i did. thank you again
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/418001/dedicated-centos-7-2-plesk-12-5-server-most-services-fail-on-boot-dbus-failure